# Detecting the device which is inputing data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webusb

I have been working on a functionality which objetive is to read barcodes & qr codes. The problem is:
I have two barcode scanners connected to my PC and would like to know from which one the data is comming from.

Here's what I have until now using the "navigator.usb":

JS Function

```
async function checkSource(e) {
     navigator.usb.getDevices()
         .then((device) => {
             console.log(device)
         })
    }
```

JSX Element (I am working with ReactJS)

```
<Input onChange={checkSource} />
```

Now, is it possible to instead of console.log a list of my connected devices, detect the one "typing" to my Input component?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are currently using your barcode scanners in a keyboard emulation mode. Ideally the `KeyboardEvent` that is dispatched for the input from the scanners would include an identifier for which "keyboard" generated the event. This is not currently how these events are specified.

If you want to use WebUSB then you will need to put the barcode scanner into a mode where it is *not* emulating a keyboard. Then you will be able to communicate directly with both devices and it will be clear which one is sending data.